# React Native Firebase: How do I add a function to Firebase Console?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-console

I'm contributing to a React Native project that uses `firebase-functions`. In the `Functions` section of the Firebase Console there's a list of existing functions, and I want to know how to add a new one. I know what code I want to write, but I don't know how to deploy it to Firebase so that it will appear in this `Functions` section of the console. A tutorial I saw said to use `firebase deploy`, but when I do that within my project it says `function 'firebase' not found`. Is there another way to add the functions to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy Cloud Functions through the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) by running `firebase deploy` or `firebase deploy --only functions`, any successfully deployed functions automatically get added to the Firebase console.

There is no separate step to get them added, nor any way to add Cloud Functions through the Firebase console. Just run `firebase deploy` and they will show up.

Comment: Ok thanks. How do I make the `firebase` function available? I'm just hesitant to add anything else to the project that might interfere with existing code.

Comment: When you deploy the functions with `firebase deploy`, they will be available to everyone and shown in the Firebase console. You will need to install the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) on your system in order for that command to be available.